# Moodle Userrole Courseid

Tags: moodle

i hope you have nice easterdays....

I need help by a special moodle-problem

I want to create a Table of Moodle-Courses
This works :-)
Now i want to check out the name of the Course-Users.... This works :-)

Now comes the problem:

How can i check out which role the course-user have in the special course?

Special: I need an SQL-Statement which gives me the User-Role (1,2,3...) form the User with the ID = 2 (User-ID) who is enroled in the course which the Id 50 (Course-ID).

Nice Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```sh
SELECT c.fullname as 'Course Name', concat(u.firstname ,' ',u.lastname) AS 'User Name', 
r.shortname as 'Role Name', r.id as 'Role ID'
FROM mdl_role_assignments AS ra
JOIN mdl_role AS r ON r.id = ra.roleid
JOIN mdl_user AS u ON u.id = ra.userid
JOIN mdl_context AS ctx ON (ctx.id = ra.contextid AND ctx.contextlevel = 50)
JOIN mdl_course AS c ON ctx.instanceid = c.id
WHERE u.id = 2 # For specific user ID
AND c.id = 50 # For a specific course, remove it if you need to see all courses.
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use any sql scripts as Moodle already provides a method for it:

$roles = get_user_roles($context, $USER->id)

Here is the moodle forum discussion on the above: [here](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=128550)